# Mex File dot product

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm trying to implement some elementary linear algebra routines in MEX files in C for practice, and I'm stuck with dot products.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#define char16_t UINT16_T //shenanigans with the compiler
#include "mex.h"

void dotProd(double *a, double *b, double z, mwSize n)
{
mwSize i;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        z+=a[i] * b[i];

    }
}

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

double z=0; //Output scalar
double *b, *a; //Input vectors

int n;

a = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); //pointer to a
b = mxGetPr(prhs[1]); //pointer to b

n = mxGetM(prhs[0]);

// Create output
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(z);

dotProd(a,b,z,(mwSize)n);
}
```

The problem is that when I test this code:

```
a=rand(2,1);
b=rand(2,1);
z=dotProd(a,b);
```

I get:

```
z=0
```

even though a and b are not orthogonal.  I verified this with the MATLAB `dot()` function.  I've picked over the code and can't quite seem to find where I'm going awry.  Some suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not returning the result of the dot product.  `z` makes a local copy of itself in your `dotProd` function.  Even though you are making modifications to `z`, those changes **are not reflected** because the scope of `z` inside `dotProd` is of **local** scope.  You need to update your function that computes the dot product to **return** something.  In addition, you are setting the output of the function **before** computing the dot product.

As such, do this:

```
// Change - Remove z as input
double dotProd(double *a, double *b, mwSize n)
{
mwSize i;
double z = 0.0; // Initialize z to 0.0
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        z+=a[i] * b[i];    
    }
return z; // Return z
}
```

Then simply do:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

double z; //Output scalar - Change - don't need to initialize
double *b, *a; //Input vectors

int n;

a = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); //pointer to a
b = mxGetPr(prhs[1]); //pointer to b

n = mxGetM(prhs[0]);

// Create output
z = dotProd(a,b, (mwSize)n); // Change - returning output
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(z);


}
```

If you **insist** on changing `z` in the function and not letting the function return anything, you'll need to pass **a pointer** to `z` and change what `z` refers to.  In other words, you would do this:

```
// Change - Make z point to a double
void dotProd(double *a, double *b, double *z, mwSize n)
{
mwSize i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        *z+=a[i] * b[i];    // Change - Refer to pointer
    }
}
```

Now, do:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

double z = 0.0;
double *b, *a; //Input vectors

int n;

a = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); //pointer to a
b = mxGetPr(prhs[1]); //pointer to b

n = mxGetM(prhs[0]);

// Create output
dotProd(a,b, &z, (mwSize)n); // Change - Pass pointer of z to function
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(z);

}
```

BTW, you still need to call `dotProd` **before** you set the output.  That's why you kept getting 0 because `z` was 0 before you set the output, then you called `dotProd` after.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!  Is there a reason why the documentation for Mex files on the Mathworks website seems to always use void functions for the computational routine?  This is part of what was confusing me in the first place.  For instance, [http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html].

Comment: Aha, in that case you are **mutating an array**.  It's customary to make those functions `void` because you're not returning anything, but you are changing the contents of an array.  Arrays are really pointers to contiguous spaces in memory, so by modifying `z` in that function you see there, you are modifying the contents of the memory that `z` is pointing to.  Note that `z` is a pointer, as well as `x` and `y`. Because you are using only single values, you'll need to either return something, or change the contents of what `z` is referring to by passing a pointer to `z`.

Comment: Thanks again, that clarifies a lot.

Comment: @Matt - My pleasure :) Good luck!  Just for curiosity, do you have background in C? If you don't, I can see why you got confused!

Comment: I don't-I'm learning C side-by-side with using Mex files.  Its a bit of a struggle, but I'm hoping to speed up some of my Matlab code this way, and expand my knowledge into another language.

Comment: @Matt - Gotcha.  Yeah that makes sense!  For now, if you're dealing with single values instead of arrays, just return the result.  Use `void` functions if you are modifying arrays and the inputs into the functions are arrays themselves.